# Cannot start Docker Compose application. Reason: compose [start] exit status 1

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-desktop

When I run a docker container I recive a error message

Cannot start Docker Compose application. Reason: compose [start] exit status 1. Container hub-api_postgres_1 Starting Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/host_mnt/Users/pedro.lima/Documents/GitHub/hub-api/docker_data/postgres': mkdir /host_mnt/Users/pedro.lima/Documents/GitHub/hub-api/docker_data/postgres: permission denied

I tried to give permition but failed

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what the problem is. What did you do to try to provide compose with permissions against the parent path, `/host_mnt/Users/pedro.lima/Documents/GitHub/hub-api/docker_data`? Note every directory above the last will need the [execute permission](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21252/353337) bit set for the account you're privileging, so that it can operate in those directories.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo mkdir -p /Users/{user}/Documents/GitHub/hub-api/docker_data/postgres

sudo chown -R your_uid:your_gid /Users/{user}/Documents/GitHub/hub-api/docker_data/postgres
```

and use

```
id
```

to se the uid and gid